# Getting PHP and MySQL to read url

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to be able to use a WHERE command in SQL to select certain values from a table. This is my current code however it doesn't work

```
$MobileNumber = $_GET["MobileNumber"];
$TeamGroup = $_GET["TeamGroup"];

if($_REQUEST=['MobileNumber']) {
    $Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item WHERE MobileNumber = $MobileNumber";
} elseif($_REQUEST=['TeamGroup']) {
    $Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item WHERE TeamGroup = $TeamGroup";
} else {
    $Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item";
};

$result = mysql_query($Item) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    print '<table><tr>';
    foreach($row as $name => $value) {
        print "<th>$name</th>";
    }
    print '</tr>';

    while($row) {
        print '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value) {
            print "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        print '</tr>';
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
    print '</table>';    
} else {
    echo "No Items Assigned";
};
```

It works for when the url is `test.php?MobileNumber=...` but not when its has TeamGroup or nothing in the url.  The url I have is like this: `test.php?TeamGroup=11`

EDIT: Added more code to let you see what I am trying to display

Comment: You need to put quotes around string values

Comment: Post more code. I'm not sure the statements in your if/elseif statements are doing what you think.

Comment: `if($_REQUEST=['MobileNumber']){` this doesnt seems to be a valid syntax.

Comment: All of the PHP mysql_* functions are deprecated, you should switch to mysqli_* versions of the functions (http://php.net/mysql_query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if($_REQUEST=['MobileNumber']){` its a wrong syntax

Try this

add this line in your `url ?MobileNumber=Put your mobile num here`. Thanks

than for Team group again this `?TeamGroup=put team group here`.

```
if($_GET['MobileNumber']==TRUE){
$MobileNumber=$_GET['MobileNumber'];
$Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item WHERE MobileNumber = $MobileNumber";
}
elseif($_GET['TeamGroup']==TRUE){
$TeamGroup=$_GET['TeamGroup'];
$Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item WHERE TeamGroup = $TeamGroup";
}
else{
    $Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item";
    }
```

Comment: It seems to be kind of working however it still doesnt like TeamGroup.
Its outputting : Error in query: . Unknown column '11' in 'where clause'

Comment: @masterjjb first check the updated answer. it will work second if its say unknown colum That simply mean you got the column name wrong. so correct it will work. Thanks

Comment: I've thoroughly check it and the column names seem to be correct

Comment: @masterjjb you told me its unknown colum 11, you are telling other people unknown column 'DH' you dont have this column in all of your code here. Thanks clarfiy please

Comment: Ok I fixed it by putting '$TeamGroup' in the WHERE clause as i was using letters sometimes. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare something using if condition then it must be like this

```
if(something == true){
  // then do something
}
else{
  //do something
}
```

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) for more

What you are trying to do is not a valid one in php.You need to change this

```
if($_REQUEST=['MobileNumber']){
```

I think you can try like this

```
if(isset($_GET['MobileNumber']) && trim($_GET['MobileNumber'])){
```

And

```
elseif(isset($_GET['TeamGroup']) && trim($_GET['TeamGroup'])){
```

Comment: How can i make it so that it check the URL to see if it includes MobileNumber or TeamGroup?

Comment: I seem to be getting: Error in query: . Unknown column 'DH' in 'where clause'

However ive checked the column names and it all seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

**this should work...**

```
if(isset($_GET['MobileNumber']))  //can also use if(isset($_GET['MobileNumber']) && !empty($_GET['MobileNumber']))
{
    $Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item WHERE MobileNumber = ".$MobileNumber;
} 
elseif(isset($_GET['TeamGroup']))
{
    $Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item WHERE TeamGroup = ".$TeamGroup";
}
else{
    $Item = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Item";
}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error as if I use the ==TRUE command instead

Comment: first use `print_r($_GET)` at the top of your php page to check what are the values you are getting.

Comment: change  `$MobileNumber"` into `".$MobileNumber` and check

Comment: Ok I fixed it by putting '$TeamGroup' in the WHERE clause as i was using letters sometimes. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
if($_REQUEST=['MobileNumber'])
```

will always be true, because you're assigning the ['MobileNumber'] array to the $_REQUEST global.

If you're trying to check whether the values are set in the $_REQUEST global, do the following:

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['MobileNumber']))
```

Comment: i have posted the same but just before you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$MobileNumber = $_GET["MobileNumber"];
$TeamGroup    = $_GET["TeamGroup"];

if(isset($_GET["MobileNumber"])) {
    //If you enclose fields/table in `` and values in '' you won't run into quoting issues
    //It's OK to not quote numbers, but you can quote them to stay standard
    $Item = "SELECT `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` FROM `Item` WHERE `MobileNumber` = '$MobileNumber'";
};
if(isset($_GET["TeamGroup"])) {
    $Item = "SELECT `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` FROM `Item` WHERE `TeamGroup` = '$TeamGroup'";
};
if(!isset($_GET["MobileNumber"]) && !isset($_GET["TeamGroup"])) {
    $Item = "SELECT `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` FROM `Item`";
};

//Switch to mysqli_*
$result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $Item) or die ("Error in query: $Item. " . mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    print '<table><tr>';
    foreach($row as $name => $value) {
        print "<th>$name</th>";
    };
    print '</tr>';

    while($row) {
        print '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value) {
            print "<td>$value</td>";
        };
        print '</tr>';
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    };
    print '</table>';    
} else {
    echo "No Items Assigned";
};
```

That

- moves from mysql_* to mysqli_* (check my syntax - most of the mysqli_* functions are the same but there are a few differences)
- uses isset & !isset to determine which query to use
- encloses your query string in ticks and quotes to help make sure you don't forget to quote something properly
- fixes your `or die` catch (you were referencing $query which didn't seem to exist)